# Implement a method that performs actions on it's calling object in Vue (like OOP)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, oop, vuejs2

Is it possible to create a method in vue that performs actions on it's calling object? (just like in OOP)

For example:

```
data() {
  return {
    players: [
      {
        hand: [],
        draw(n) { /* darws n cards */ },
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

so then I call it like:

```
this.players[0].draw(7);
```

or do I have to do the following?

```
methods() {
  draw(caller, n) {
    // code
  },
}
```